# Adding path to autoload works - why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on the front-end for our web app which is constructed using Angular.

The backend is a rails app with a modification to allow it to act as an API as well as a normal Rails application (pre-existing application here so it makes a-lot of sense to keep it)

I'm using JWT's on the front-end to validate a user but I also issue a refresh_token so they can get a new JWT after a certain amount of time. The code looks like this:

```
def delegation
  user = User.user_from_refresh_token params[:refresh_token]
  render json: {jwt: user.generate_auth_token}
end
```

This is setup as a POST in the route file:

```
post  "auth/delegation"
```

So the line in question is this one:

```
user = User.user_from_refresh_token params[:refresh_token]
```

which would mean you'd expect the `user.rb` model to contain a method called `user_from_refresh_token` which I do:

```
def self.user_from_refresh_token token
    refresh_token = RefreshToken.find_by!(token: token)
    raise API::Unauthorized.new("This refresh token has been revoked") if refresh_token.revoked?
    find(refresh_token.user_id)
  end
```

But the error that I get when I call this is:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `user_from_refresh_token' for User
```

**Question 1** - How come I can't call this like it is? Shouldn't this just work?

Note:
I fixed this issue by modifying the autoloader to add this in:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib #{config.root}/model/concerns)
```

**Question 2** - Why does this have to be done in order for the previous part to work?

Comment: Do you have anything loaded from `lib` with some overrides, or it was just fixed by having `spring` restart whole app due to config change?

Comment: @Vasfed the user.rb model exists in another gem which is why the override was occurring but even with that it's still confusing as to why it was being overwritten by another gem given the location of the file I was working on